# Samsung agency is buying off Stack Overflow users

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, community

I was thinking anybody on Stack Overflow might be interested in the blog post *[Samsung agency is buying off StackOverflow users](https://web.archive.org/web/20130801174814/http://delyan.me/08-01-2013/samsung-agency-is-buying-off-stackoverflow-users/)*.

How can the Stack Overflow community defend itself from such spam attempts?

Comment: I'd say users who go with the suggested practices will pretty soon find out the community's view on it all.

Comment: As written in the post, they’d be downvoted to −∞. Also, it says in the post that he contacted SO already. Also, did you see the comments? e.g. by [Bill the Lizard](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard)?

Comment: The author of your link pretty much says it all: *"it's clear that this guy is totally out of touch with what StackOverflow is"* ... Nothing to worry about I'd say.

Comment: We defend it with fire! http://i.imgur.com/8WOhrMO.png

Comment: The part that really saddens me about this is that people think the troll using the Matt Cutts name in the comments there is the real Matt Cutts.

Comment: But he said he's Matt Cutts from Google @BradLarson? What more proof do you want?

Comment: @Bart I know! It's not like anyone would go on the internet and lie or anything...

Comment: lol, from the agency's web site: `Paying for followers will not get you the results you need. Follower growth needs to be organic. We like to keep things All Natural here at FLLU. It's all about Organic Growth!`

Comment: @Pekka웃 Just like the real flu...

Comment: ["Please note that our request to promote via these public channels is a breach against their Terms of Service and could result in your account being terminated."](http://pastebin.com/EVm8jH3s)

Comment: @Richard what? No gif?

Comment: Other titles considered for this post:  `Help prevent Stack Overflow from catching the FLLU`, and `Does Stack Overflow have it's FLLU shots?`.

Comment: Seriously though, this is a really interesting post, and I'm glad to see the responses from the moderators so quickly.

Comment: @LBT I support the `Help prevent Stack Overflow from catching the FLLU` title campaign.

Comment: @LBT those aren't moderators, they're Stack Exchange employees. :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 their organic growth is as organic as organic food, I think that marketing dummies believe everyone is so expressed with the words they don't understand as they.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In this case, we saw the post and reached out directly to Samsung (not the agency) and they are taking steps to make sure this does not happen again. There's no need to contact us about this issue anymore unless you receive a new request *after* Aug1, 2013.  But if you receive something like this in the future, please do reach out to Stack Exchange (the company) via https://stackoverflow.com/contact.

Comment: Good guy SO: stops spam before it happens

Comment: You *could* have waited for my my $500 check to clear, you know.

Comment: The handbag business not working too well for you at the moment @Pekka웃?

Comment: I'll bet a beer that "fllu" is actually a front for Samsung itself that they can hide behind when something like this comes out. A "digital agency" that doesn't even reveal where it is based, no corporate info, and a twitter feed full of pointless BS?  Who in their right mind is going to hire someone like that?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Could also be nepotism, and that agency is just a relative of some Samsung manager. But that doesn't matter in any case, Samsung is responsible for the companies or contractors they hire, and they shouldn't be able to hide behind them.

Comment: @Pekka웃: CrunchBase says South Korean company founded in 2007 as a blog and has grown from there.

Comment: @user7116 ah, cool, thanks! Then their Twitter feed makes even less sense. But well....

Comment: I just found this blog post... hypocritical? http://www.fllu.com/digital-growth-has-to-be-organic/2012/12/03/

Comment: @user7116 The contact address in their WHOIS record suggests that they are based in Los Angeles.

Answer (score 26):

Thanks to the folks who reached out to us last night, I contacted the parties involved.

### This should be resolved.

If you got one of these sketchy offers, you should have received an additional communication this morning telling you to ignore it.

The agency involved apologized and provided us the info we need to reasonably ensure that they have corrected it.

No need to contact us unless you receive any NEW requests to post spam.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure they're _really sorry_. I just lost a tremendous amount of respect for that company.