# Unable to change vote or unvote answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Currently unable to change vote or unvote **answers** on the Android app.

Error message is:

> Upvote/Downvote failed: You have already voted on this question

Even the error message is wrong, should be "**answer**" instead of "**question**".

Furthermore, the vote circles do not change colour to indicate the vote.

Please help to verify this as well.

I'm using Samsung S3 *mini*, model number I8190N, running stock 4.1.2 if it helps.

Comment: Android? Samsung?? CONSPIRACY: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191441/185714

Comment: couldn't edit the question on the app (see related meta question posted earlier about this). anyway, changing or unvoting works fine on questions (went back to verify again), but not answers.

Comment: sorry @mansfield, can't click on links in comments in the app (see another related question posted earlier on this)

Comment: It was a joke anyway :P

Comment: That comment was a joke based on some shady dealings by a Samsung publicist recently ;)

Comment: Is there an official android app?

Comment: @RichardTingle http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app?rq=1

Comment: The vote error message should be fixed but I won't mark this status-completed until the vote preservation is complete on answers.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these issues should be resolved.